# Are these theorems really provable in PRA?

Tags: logic

In [this article](http://home.uchicago.edu/%7Ewwtx/PRA2.pdf), Tait claims that $0 = 1 \Rightarrow \phi$ and $((\phi \Rightarrow 0 = 1) \Rightarrow0 = 1) \Rightarrow \phi$ are theorems of PRA (at least, of the formalization of PRA in this article, which employs a bit of type theory). Are there any proofs of these theorems, then?

Comment: I mean, PRA proves $0\neq 1$, so $0=1$ would be a contradiction. Then use Explosion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I forgot to mention that, curiously, Tait's formalization does not include the axiom $0 \neq S(x)$, which is used in the proof of $0 \neq 1$ I know. Can PRA prove $0 \neq 1$ without this axiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tait's system does what he claims, but it seems to require some work to verify this.

First, notice that, for any two terms $a$ and $b$ of the same finitist type $A$, the primitive recursion construction of PRA provides a function $f:\mathbb N\to A$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n')=b$ for all $n$. In particular, $f(0')=b$. So if $0=0'$ then $a=b$ (because Tait's logic includes the usual axioms and rules of identity). Thus, from $0=0'$, we can deduce all the atomic formulas (equations) of Tait's system. Then, thanks to the laws of implication that are also included in Tait's logic, we can deduce all formulas; they're implications, and thus they follow from their consequents. That is, repeatedly apply the rule "from $\phi$ deduce $\psi\to\phi$."

This gives the first claim: $0=0'\to\phi$. To get the second claim, we need another law of implication: From $(\phi\to\psi)\to\psi$ and $\psi\to\phi$, deduce $\phi$. To see that this is a valid rule of inference, just write out the truth table (or convince yourself that $(\phi\to\psi)\to\psi$ is equivalent to $\phi\lor\psi$) (or check that $((\phi\to\psi)\to\phi)\to\phi$ is a tautology). Now apply that rule with $0=0'$ as $\psi$, and use the fact that we've already proved $0=0'\to\phi$. So we get that $(\phi\to\psi)\to\psi$ implies $\phi$, as required.

(Side comment: The laws of implication mentioned in the last paragraph above are valid in classical logic but not in intuitionistic logic. That's unavoidable, because what's being proved, essentially the law of double-negation, is not intuitionistically valid.)

Comment: I know that the second theorem (which is a form of double negation elimination) should be provable within PRA with intuitionistic logic (because so is the analogue law of excluded middle), so wouldn't introducing logical axioms which are intuitionistically valid be unnecessary to prove the second theorem? The point is precisely to prove that $0 = 1$ is a classical contradiction and, therefore, that $\phi \Rightarrow 0 = 1$ is equivalent to the classical negation of $\phi$, doing away with the necessity of introducing classical negation and its logical axioms to the postulates of the system.

Comment: @noname_lonestar  I don't understand your comment. It reads as though intuitionistic logic had more axioms than classical, whereas the reverse is actually the case.

Comment: that is not what I meant to say at all. What I said is that classical logic has additional logical axioms in comparison with intuitionistic logic which are unnecessary in PRA since the theory proves the same theorems (including logical theorems) over either logic.